# JPanel scrollbar

Tags: java, swing

Собственно у меня есть фрейм. На фрейме находиться панель, на панеле находиться еще панель. Данная панель у меня работает с graphics.

Вопрос :

Как добавить в данную панель скролбар. Перепробовал множество способов. Например : на фрейме есть панель и на нее добавить скролбар, работает. Но если то же самое провернуть с панелью в панеле, она пропадает.

Comment: [Не пропадает](http://pastebin.com/GpR45E6E). Что я не понял из ваших объяснений?

Comment: @zRrr вот так получилось, пробовал оракловские примеры. Осталось теперь понять как Graphics внутри скролить

Comment: Проще, по-моему, выставить/переопределить preferred size для панели с графикой по размеру графики, засунуть панель в `JScrollPane` и либо при рисовании положиться на встроенное отсечение, либо брать `Graphics.getClipBounds()` и рисовать объекты, попадающие в "грязный" регион.

Comment: @zRrr спасибо огромное, помогли! ненавижу работать с UI. Оформите пожалуйста все как один ответ, чтобы завершить данный вопрос.